# How does "yum update" ensure it won't cause problem?

Tags: kernel, yum

it seems that by doing `yum update`, lower release version such as CentOS 6.2 would be updated to CentOS 6.8 dy doing this [link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60660/minor-upgrades-and-version-numbers-on-centos).

how does yum gurrantee that things would not go wrong in this process? especially consider kernel upgrade is usually deemed a dangerous operation.

Answer (score 1):

`yum` **does not** guarantee that you will or will not be having problems with your server after the upgrade. That is why an upgrade in a test server is necessary before upgrading a production server.

Comment: How do you build a test server if you don't have one for the older machines?